# c++ struct array definition

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am wondering if there is a better way to simply create a struct containing an array with a SIZE:

```
...
#define SIZE 100;
...

struct foo {
    foo();
    bar * bars;
}

foo::foo() {
bars = new bar[SIZE];
}
```

Comment: Sure: `struct foo { foo(); std::array<bar, SIZE> bars; };`

Comment: Well, `SIZE` is a compile time constant, so you do not need a dynamically alocated array. You can have a `bar bars[SIZE]` data member.

Comment: @chris, you have unbalanced `<>` ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, Oops. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4):

as long as `SIZE` is a compile-time constant you can simply

```
struct foo {
    bar bars[SIZE];
}
```